# How to pass variables from each ajax call into the 1 drawchart function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-visualization

Building on from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525527/multiple-ajax-requests-from-one-page-how-to-do-best-practice/)

I have the following code that draws 2 charts based on 2 ajax calls.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
}).then(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(drawChart1);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(drawChart2);
});

function drawChart1(result) {
  ...
}

function drawChart2(result) {
  ...
}
```

I am looking at code reuse here. **How can I pass variables from each ajax call into the 1 `drawChart` function?** And where would I define the variables in each ajax call before passing them to the draw chart function?

I imagine it would look something like:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(drawChart,variable1,variable2);
...

function drawChart(result,variable1,variable2) {
  ...
  //draw chart at variable1 position
  //draw chart at variable2 position
  //variable 1 & 2 would be ids for where I want the charts to be drawn
}
```

Note: I am currently reading [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts) to try solve this.

### EDIT1 - Answer is something like below, kudos

```
              $.ajax({
            url: 'data.php',
            dataType: 'json'
          }).done(function(jsonData) {
            drawChart(jsonData, "variable1", "variable2");
          })

          function drawChart(result, v1, v2) {

            console.log("drawChart called")
            console.log("result")
            console.log(result)
            console.log("v1")
            console.log(v1)
            console.log("v2")
            console.log(v2)
          }
```

Comment: check the snippet under __EDIT 2__ in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49924122/5090771)...

Comment: tks got that to work